# jQuery slider is unknown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

How does this slider work?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider

source given shows up nothing

```
<style>
    #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; }
</style>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider();
    });
</script>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

I did include jquery before adding this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it gives me

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'slider'

error.

This is what entire code looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            #demo-frame > div.demo { padding: 10px !important; }
        </style>

        <div class="demo">
            <div id="slider"></div>
        </div><!-- End demo -->

        <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider" ).slider();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've found your problem, checkout my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did include jquery before adding this

You did include jQuery... but you are using `jQuery ui` plugin method- `.slider()` without referencing the ui plugin.
So that method `slider` is unknown to javascript,

Add the reference **after** the jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Update:**

After too much time spent, I've found your problem, you're missing the **JQuery ui css**:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/GJBCp/)**

Comment: @Sparky672 (in reply to your now deleted comment) okay... this seems more involved than I thought. It said nowhere in http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ that I need images: "The jQuery UI Slider plugin uses the jQuery UI CSS Framework to style its look and feel, including colors and background textures." If I need extra images where do I get those? Or do I have to make my own?

Comment: @Nitin, I deleted my last comment because I thought you were trying to construct an image/content slider.  It's an overlap in terminology and it's my fault for not looking closer.  Disregard.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using jQuery UI for the slider.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"/>`

Comment: I thought it would be nice to inform you what was his second problem, he was missing the juqery ui **css**.

Comment: yup, isn't it always the simplest of things! +1 for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a **jQuery UI** Slider, you are missing **jQuery UI** which needs to be included after jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: That URL is valid [try it](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js)

Comment: @gdoron: ok got it.  It's technically valid.  I'd never leave off the scheme but that's just me.